# Highcharts-spline chart's spline disappears and appears on hover

Tags: javascript, highcharts, polymer, node-webkit, spline

I am using highcharts 4.1.7 to draw a spline chart on node webkit (nwjs-v0.12.2-win-ia32) browser engine. I am using polymer version 0.5.

Scenario:
I have a tabbed interface using paper-tabs and core-pages. In each view I have spline charts drawn, with start and stop buttons. I start a chart and it renders, then i stop it, switch to another tab and come back to my old tab, now I can only see dots of the spline chart , but on hovering over them the line appears. I have tried calling a chart.redraw() on switch of tabs but it doesn't work.

Also I have 'connectNulls: true' for my series.

I wish I could post a running example but I am unable to do it due to large amounts of code and also workplace restrictions.

Note: When a column graph is involved it works fine. Also this issue is not observed when I used an older version of node-webkit like 0.9.2.But the present requirement is to upgrade to the newer one.

Comment: Try version 1, maybe there is bug on .5. As a workaround till you find the main reason why its doing that you could set the highchart div css to (display:none;) as you go from tab to tab and then (display:"") as you are about to view the page. I used this method for dialog pages so i could hide the contents of the main page or the other way round for faster response. give that a go maybe it will work

Comment: And solution for Highcharts - isntead of `chart.redraw()` try `chart.series[0].update()`. It is probably problem with showing/hiding element in 0.9.2 version.

Comment: Is using chart.series[0].show() better than chart.series[0].update() in terms of efficiency? Does show() do an internal redraw, I suspect it does. Do let me know your thoughts

Comment: @Tasos : I tried with your suggestion but it gives a slight flicker when you hide/unhide the div. If there's any way where we can avoid that, it would be perfect.

Comment: try setting it to the hardware graphics  layer by adding css  (transform: translate3d(0,0,0);) or (transform: translateZ(0);) to the tabs or highcharts div and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

After playing around, I found that chart.series[0].show() works in most of the cases I needed but I'm not sure if a redraw is called internally on show().

Comment: You can use setVisible and add parameter for redraw. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setVisible

Comment: Thanks.Ultimately a redraw true needs to be called even with this option - chArray[i].series[0].setVisible (true,true), it doesn't work with just the first param set to true and the other to false. The whole idea is to avoid a redraw but I guess that's inevitable.